# Angular does correct routing, but address bar does not change for child routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

using Angular 6
(1) here is the route array

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'administration',
        children: [
        {
            path: 'users',
            component: UserListComponent,
            resolve: { userList: UserListResolverService }
        },
        {
            path: 'user-groups',
            component: UserGroupListComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'permissions',
            component: PermissionComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: UserListComponent,
            resolve: { userList: UserListResolverService }
        }
    ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'PageNotFoundComponent',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];
```

(2) Click any sub-menu under parent menu of Administration, the route works and display the correct component templates. 
    e.g., it displays a list of user groups by clicking User Groups. However, the url address bar stays as http://localhost:46325/administration no matter which child links I click.

```
The route tracing has correct url though
e.g., NavigationStart {id: 16, url: "/administration/user-groups", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks so much.

Comment: can you format your question so it is more readable?

Comment: { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' } isn't this a mistake on the path specified?

Comment: Sorry my format was gone for whatever reason.

Comment: it actually should be { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' } . thanks.

Comment: Can you use StackBlitz and create a [mcve]?

Comment: no. I have only one router-outlet. all components share the same outlet. I thought about creating a new outlet, but I did not find it's necessary.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Deborah - I'll try to create an Administration component with only a new router outlet in its template. Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm wrong. I didn't notice that your administration component is a *component-less* route. You should *not* need another `router-outlet` in that case. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Does the `NavigationEnd` also show the full url? Do you have `{ skipLocationChange: true }` set anywhere in your code? (That prevents update of the URL)

Comment: yes there were a few places which had { skipLocationChange: true }. Removing these solved my issue. I've tried to fix this issue several times. I'm very grateful to you. Thank you so much .